# how to rename multiple files 00001.png to 000001.png

Tags: ffmpeg, rename, batch-rename

how to rename multiple files 00001.png to 000001.png basically add 1 more 0 to it
the folder has 200,000 pngs. as 00001.png,00002.png,00003.png,00004.png,00005.png......

everything is in order , after 99999.png the next on is 100000.png but **from 00001.png to 99999.png i would like 000001.png to 099999.png**

dont really know effective ways also i not a coder, so max i cant do is pretty much copy paste a code or somethinng into a .bat file or powershell and run it :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will work on windows, but you could try paste this in your powerShell **being located in the folder which you have the files to rename**.

```
 for file in $(ls .); mv "$file" "0$file";
```

Comment: OP seems to be hobbled with Windows so this is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %i in (0????.png) do ren %i 0%i
```